# Is there an easy way to convert the "font" style property to each of it's individual style?

Tags: javascript, css

For instance:

Here is a style object:

```
{
    font: normal normal bold 14px/14px arial,
    color: black
}
```

I would like the corrected object to be something like:

```
{
    fontStyle: normal,
    fontVariant: normal,
    fontWeight: bold,
    fontSize: 14px,
    lineHeight: 14px,
    fontFamily: arial,
    color: black
}
```

I could easily split the string up and parse out each property, but sometimes all properties might not be present. You may, for example receive a style object that is something like:

```
{
    font: bold 14px arial
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Part of a script I'm writing sends style objects to a server. Because this may happen many times per second, I'm comparing the last style object I sent to the server, with the one I'm about to send, then sending only the deltas so as to minimize the amount of data being sent.

Comment: Using `font:` should be avoided all together. See the yellow box on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font for details.

Comment: ThiefMaster, I completely agree. It's unavoidable, in this case, as text being pasted into the safari browser forces the receiving input (in my case an editable div) to use this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the style has actually been applied to an element, then on current browsers you can use:

```
window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(...)
```

to extract the value of the individual fields (e.g. `font-family`, `line-height`)

Answer (score 0):

Which part are you having a problem with? There's an order of properties and some acceptable values for each property, just go through them skipping properties that don't have any valid values for that property

Comment: I considered that, but some properties can have values that are the same. "Normal" and "inherit" are two examples.

Comment: I still don't see a problem, you first look for style, which does accept inherit and normal, so if it says normal it's the style, the next property is then variant, look for valid properties for that